# Subset dataframe based on index substring that matches the index of another dataframe in unspecified order

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset `anno_GSE159115` based on the substring of its index that matches any value in `adata.obs.index`, regardless of order. My code does not return all the matches when I use `isin`.

```
anno_GSE159115[anno_GSE159115.index.str.rsplit("_", 1).str[-1].isin(adata.obs.index)]
```

Input:

`anno_GSE159115`

```
pd.DataFrame({'no_genes': {'SI_18854_AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 3255,
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCACTGGG-1': 3807,
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCTTTCTC-1': 2770,
  'SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAACTGCT-1': 2185,
  'SI_18854_AAACGGGCAAGGTTTC-1': 2741,
  'SI_18854_AAACGGGGTTCACGGC-1': 4417,
  'SI_18854_AAACGGGGTTCTGTTT-1': 3292,
  'SI_18854_AAACGGGGTTTACTCT-1': 4335,
  'SI_18854_AAAGATGAGATCTGAA-1': 3042,
  'SI_18854_AAAGATGCACGTCTCT-1': 3019,
  'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTGATAAAC-1': 6192,
  'SI_18854_AAAGATGGTTTGGGCC-1': 1099,
  'SI_18854_AAAGCAAGTACTTCTT-1': 2107,
  'SI_18854_AAAGCAAGTACTTGAC-1': 2636,
  'SI_18854_AAAGCAATCCTTGCCA-1': 4950,
  'SI_18854_AAAGTAGGTCCAGTTA-1': 1889,
  'SI_18854_AAAGTAGTCACCAGGC-1': 3031,
  'SI_18854_AAAGTAGTCAGGTAAA-1': 2251,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCAGTAAGTAC-1': 1389,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCGTTCAACCA-1': 4068,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCTCAGTTAGC-1': 2400,
  'SI_18854_AAATGCCTCGATAGAA-1': 2205,
  'SI_18854_AACACGTGTACTCGCG-1': 2775,
  'SI_18854_AACACGTTCACCAGGC-1': 2400,
  'SI_18854_AACCATGAGTAAGTAC-1': 1687,
  'SI_18854_AACCATGCAGCCTGTG-1': 1733,
  'SI_18854_AACCATGCAGTCGTGC-1': 1785,
  'SI_18854_AACCATGTCTCGGACG-1': 2397,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGAGGGAAACA-1': 2160,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGCACGAAGCA-1': 2972,
  'SI_18854_AACCGCGCAGTCAGCC-1': 5695,
  'SI_18854_AACGTTGCACCATCCT-1': 4423,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTCCGTCAG-1': 2558,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGGTGTTGAGG-1': 2443,
  'SI_18854_AACTCAGTCCGCGCAA-1': 1196,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCAGAAGGTTT-1': 3257,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCAGCTTCGCG-1': 2019,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCAGGCCGAAT-1': 1526,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCAGGTGGGTT-1': 4833,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCCAGTCGTGC-1': 5175,
  'SI_18854_AACTCCCGTGCATCTA-1': 3545,
  'SI_18854_AACTCTTAGATGGCGT-1': 1741,
  'SI_18854_AACTCTTAGGACGAAA-1': 2242,
  'SI_18854_AACTCTTCACATGGGA-1': 1975,
  'SI_18854_AACTCTTTCCAGAAGG-1': 2780,
  'SI_18854_AACTGGTGTCAACATC-1': 2160,
  'SI_18854_AACTGGTGTGGAAAGA-1': 2631,
  'SI_18854_AACTTTCAGCTAGTTC-1': 2983,
  'SI_18854_AACTTTCAGGATGGAA-1': 2177,
  'SI_18854_AACTTTCAGTATGACA-1': 5198,
  'SI_18854_AACTTTCGTGACAAAT-1': 1687,
  'SI_18854_AAGACCTCAGACACTT-1': 2319,
  'SI_18854_AAGACCTTCAACTCTT-1': 2983,
  'SI_18854_AAGACCTTCTTGTCAT-1': 4303,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCGTACCGCTG-1': 4485,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCGTTTAAGCC-1': 2863,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCTCAGTTAGC-1': 3569,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCTCCACGTTC-1': 6725,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCTCGTTACAG-1': 2497,
  'SI_18854_AAGCCGCTCTCGCATC-1': 3358,
  'SI_18854_AAGGAGCAGTACGTTC-1': 1734,
  'SI_18854_AAGGAGCGTTCTCATT-1': 1513,
  'SI_18854_AAGGAGCTCCAGAGGA-1': 1614,
  'SI_18854_AAGGAGCTCCCAAGTA-1': 2350,
  'SI_18854_AAGGCAGCAAAGTGCG-1': 2109,
  'SI_18854_AAGGCAGCACGTCTCT-1': 3231,
  'SI_18854_AAGGCAGGTCCGAATT-1': 2112,
  'SI_18854_AAGGCAGGTCGGCACT-1': 4298,
  'SI_18854_AAGGCAGTCGGCGGTT-1': 3054,
  'SI_18854_AAGGTTCAGTCGTACT-1': 3450,
  'SI_18854_AAGTCTGAGGGAGTAA-1': 1631,
  'SI_18854_AAGTCTGAGTGTTGAA-1': 4198,
  'SI_18854_AAGTCTGGTATGAATG-1': 4625,
  'SI_18854_AAGTCTGTCTCCCTGA-1': 2152,
  'SI_18854_AATCCAGAGAAACGCC-1': 1746,
  'SI_18854_AATCCAGGTGATAAAC-1': 2176,
  'SI_18854_AATCGGTAGACAGACC-1': 3262,
  'SI_18854_AATCGGTCACGGCCAT-1': 3994,
  'SI_18854_AATCGGTGTGGAAAGA-1': 3387,
  'SI_18854_ACACCAAAGAACAATC-1': 2056,
  'SI_18854_ACACCAAAGAATTCCC-1': 5704,
  'SI_18854_ACACCAACAACAACCT-1': 5949,
  'SI_18854_ACACCCTCAAGCGAGT-1': 3208,
  'SI_18854_ACACCCTCATCATCCC-1': 2517,
  'SI_18854_ACACCCTTCGTCGTTC-1': 2313,
  'SI_18854_ACACCGGTCCCTTGCA-1': 2074,
  'SI_18854_ACACCGGTCGCTAGCG-1': 2623,
  'SI_18854_ACACTGAAGAGGGCTT-1': 3039,
  'SI_18854_ACACTGAGTAAATGAC-1': 2544,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCCGCATTAGCCA-1': 1725,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCCGGTACCGGCT-1': 2649,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCCGTCGTTTAGG-1': 1661,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCCGTCTCGCTTG-1': 3747,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCCGTCTTATCTG-1': 2595,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTAAGAACAACT-1': 2623,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTAAGGACAGAA-1': 2247,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTAAGTTTCCTT-1': 3156,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTAGTCTGCGGT-1': 1867,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTAGTGTAATGA-1': 3351,
  'SI_18854_ACAGCTATCGGAATCT-1': 2811}})
```

`adata.obs.index`

```
Index(['AAACCTGAGACGACGT-1', 'AAACCTGCACGGCTAC-1', 'AAACCTGCAGTATCTG-1',
       'AAACCTGCAGTCAGCC-1', 'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1', 'AAACCTGGTAACGTTC-1',
       'AAACCTGGTCAAGCGA-1', 'AAACCTGGTCAGTGGA-1', 'AAACCTGGTTCATGGT-1',
       'AAACCTGGTTTAGGAA-1', 'AAACCTGTCAACCATG-1', 'AAACCTGTCCGCATCT-1',
       'AAACCTGTCGCCAGCA-1', 'AAACCTGTCTATCGCC-1', 'AAACCTGTCTGACCTC-1',
       'AAACGGGAGACCCACC-1', 'AAACGGGAGTTAGCGG-1', 'AAACGGGCACTTAAGC-1',
       'AAACGGGCAGCAGTTT-1', 'AAACGGGCAGTTCCCT-1', 'AAACGGGGTAACGACG-1',
       'AAACGGGGTAAGTTCC-1', 'AAACGGGGTAGCGCAA-1', 'AAACGGGGTCCTGCTT-1',
       'AAACGGGGTCGGCTCA-1', 'AAACGGGGTCGTGGCT-1', 'AAACGGGGTTAAGATG-1',
       'AAACGGGGTTGCCTCT-1', 'AAAGATGAGCGTTGCC-1', 'AAAGATGAGCTAGTCT-1',
       'AAAGATGAGCTGAAAT-1', 'AAAGATGAGGTGCTTT-1', 'AAAGATGAGTATCGAA-1',
       'AAAGATGCAATCACAC-1', 'AAAGATGCAATCGGTT-1', 'AAAGATGCAGATCGGA-1',
       'AAAGATGCATTGAGCT-1', 'AAAGATGTCGTTTATC-1', 'AAAGATGTCTCCAGGG-1',
       'AAAGATGTCTGAGGGA-1', 'AAAGCAAAGATATGGT-1', 'AAAGCAAAGCACCGCT-1',
       'AAAGCAAAGCAGACTG-1', 'AAAGCAAAGCGCCTTG-1', 'AAAGCAAAGGCAAAGA-1',
       'AAAGCAACAGACGCCT-1', 'AAAGCAACAGTGGAGT-1', 'AAAGCAACATACAGCT-1',
       'AAAGCAAGTAAAGTCA-1', 'AAAGCAAGTGCAACTT-1', 'AAAGCAAGTTATTCTC-1',
       'AAAGCAAGTTGGTAAA-1', 'AAAGCAATCAGAAATG-1', 'AAAGCAATCGCCGTGA-1',
       'AAAGTAGAGATCGATA-1', 'AAAGTAGAGCAATATG-1', 'AAAGTAGCAGGCTCAC-1',
       'AAAGTAGCAGTTTACG-1', 'AAAGTAGGTACGAAAT-1', 'AAAGTAGGTCACAAGG-1',
       'AAAGTAGGTCAGAGGT-1', 'AAAGTAGGTCGGATCC-1', 'AAAGTAGTCAACACGT-1',
       'AAAGTAGTCACAGGCC-1', 'AAAGTAGTCACCGGGT-1', 'AAAGTAGTCAGCTCTC-1',
       'AAAGTAGTCCTCATTA-1', 'AAAGTAGTCTCCTATA-1', 'AAATGCCAGATCCTGT-1',
       'AAATGCCAGCGATCCC-1', 'AAATGCCCACCAGGCT-1', 'AAATGCCGTACAGTGG-1',
       'AAATGCCGTAGTAGTA-1', 'AAATGCCGTATCTGCA-1', 'AAATGCCTCAACACGT-1',
       'AAATGCCTCAGCCTAA-1', 'AAATGCCTCGAATCCA-1', 'AAATGCCTCTGCCCTA-1',
       'AAATGCCTCTGCGACG-1', 'AAATGCCTCTGTCCGT-1', 'AACACGTAGACTGTAA-1',
       'AACACGTAGCGATTCT-1', 'AACACGTCACTTACGA-1', 'AACACGTCATGCCTAA-1',
       'AACACGTCATGGTAGG-1', 'AACACGTGTCAACATC-1', 'AACACGTTCAGTTGAC-1',
       'AACACGTTCGAGCCCA-1', 'AACACGTTCGCACTCT-1', 'AACACGTTCTTCTGGC-1',
       'AACCATGAGACCGGAT-1', 'AACCATGAGCAGCGTA-1', 'AACCATGCACTTAAGC-1',
       'AACCATGCAGATTGCT-1', 'AACCATGCATGTTGAC-1', 'AACCATGGTCCAGTGC-1',
       'AACCATGGTGTGCGTC-1', 'AACCATGTCCCAGGTG-1', 'AACCATGTCGGCATCG-1',
       'AACCATGTCTCCAACC-1'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Your example is not really reproducible, there is no match. Can you explain which rows are missing?

Comment: Do the sequences all have 16 nucleotides? IS the trailing number `-1` important?

Comment: Not necessarily all the sequences have 16 nucleotides. The trailing `-1` is important. I've updated my example.

Comment: Do you expect any overlap? There is still none in the updated example

Comment: There might be overlap.

Comment: it might be helpful to provide a desired output, seeing as it's unclear what that would be in this case

Comment: @Anon let's put it this way, what you currently show "works" as expected, so the question should be closed for not being reproducible. You must clearly demonstrate the problem with a minimal reproducible example, which isn't the case currently.